# What do I need to go along with my new SLA 3D printer?

Tags: sla

I just purchased an [Anycubic Photon 3S](https://www.anycubic.com/products/anycubic-photon-3d-printer) LCD-based SLA 3D printer. I understand the need for cleaning and curing parts after printing. While the device is in transit, I'm looking to set up a workstation to use it with.

Are there any recommendations for accessories to buy?: Particular containers to store materials in, particular products for cleaning prints (or cleaning the machine), particular lamps for curing, etc.

I'm trying to avoid gotchas, and I've got time to visit hardware stores or make further online purchases before it arrives. I'm not asking about software or computing hardware, just things that I'll want to have "on the bench".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Safety Gear

Gloves, you want to wear them whenever handling any resin. Single-use gloves are best - dispose of them after use. Consider them contaminated after touching anything in contact with resin and toss them before handling anything that shall not get in contact with resin. That includes door handles.

A good idea is to also wear eye protection, as resin in the eyes could destroy them.

While a dust mask might not be strictly necessary, it could reduce your exposure to the fumes of resin. Some resin fumes are known to create hypersensitivity.

It is also a good idea to put the printer into a dedicated workspace that is well ventilated and not your primary living space. I strongly recommend reading both [Best way to deal with Resin Printers in your living space](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/8594/best-way-to-deal-with-resin-printers-in-your-living-space) and [Safe way of disposing resin](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7305/safe-way-of-disposing-resin/7307#7307)

## Post-Processing Station

You may want to build a post-processing station. Most pieces can be sourced in any home depot store or made from household items, so I don't recommend specific brands but the requirements.

#### Washing Station

A typical post-processing station consists of at least 2 vats large enough to submerge your print volume in, so you can wash off your print in the first and then wash it with fresh liquid in the second. The typical liquids for cleaning are isopropyl alcohol and sometimes technical alcohol. Some resins demand special liquids that are specific to the type of resin. Best, the washing vats have securely sealing lids. Glass is preferably as it is easy to clean.

To use the least amount of cleaning liquid, you might want to have a pair of [needle spray bottles](https://www.google.com/search?q=needle%20spray%20bottle) - one for each bath. Label them!

To avoid spillage and ruining tables, a plastic table cloth can be a good addition. Fold it with the contaminated side onto itself for storage. A different solution would be to put the cleaning station onto a ceramic or steel surface, which can be easily cleaned after use.

#### Curing Station/Chamber

The next step is curing the print under direct exposure to a UV light source, somewhat akin to how gel nails are hardened. Sometimes the sun is enough.

Since the resin residue from washing is now in the isopropyl alcohol (or other washing liquid), treat it as chemical waste. To reduce the waste of material, flock out the resin in it by exposing the liquid to the UV light and filter the result. The result is Isopropyl Alcohol with some remaining contaminants, which can be used again for the first rinsing step.

## Other Tools

Besides cleaning and curing the print, you need to remove the print from the plate, so you need a spatula or scraper, which is reserved only for your SLA printer. Never use it on the build platform of your FDM printers and consider it contaminated with uncured resin after use. Best cure residue on it in the UV chamber and then physically chip off the hardened resin before handling it without gloves again.

Similarly, a tool to stir the resin and remove flakes is often used, and some makers have special spatulas to clean the vat. Clean them well after use.

You will want to have some nice snippets to remove the support structures at some spots and some pliers to break them free - safety first.

Needle files and sanding paper for cleanup where the support stuck are a given.

## Resin Recovery

Since the resin in the trays might harden over time, you'll want to have some sort of rig to hold the vat at a tilted angle upside down so it can flow out, back into the resin bottle. A cover might also help to reduce exposure and allow short time storage in the machine. [Thingieverse has a couple of solutions](https://www.thingiverse.com/search?q=resin%20vat&dwh=475d8d188363603) for lids, pouring and filtering stations as well as other accessories. Look for those that fit your printer.

The Resin should be stored in airtight and light-blocking bottles. As an extra security measure, you should store the resin in a closed cupboard to prevent light exposure through not totally opaque bottles.

More on Re-using resin can be found [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/14497/left-over-photopolymer-resins/14500#14500)

### Further Reading/watching

- [Angus/Makers Muse on 3D printing safety](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kHcsTG9QsM)
- [A rather good guide regarding Resin 3D printing](https://www.wargaming3d.com/2018/12/31/the-complete-and-utter-idiots-guide-to-3d-printing-in-resin-for-wargamers/)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a tub for cleaning the print, some funnels to get leftover resin back into the bottel, gloves, since you really don't want to get any uncured resin on your skin and a strong UV light for finishing the curing process after the cleaning

Comment: Only today, an article I read suggested to use caution when handling the isopropyl alcohol after it is used to clean the part. The IPA now contains uncured resin and can cause additional contact problems (health-wise). I have in the past read that it's a good idea to expose the rinse bath to sunlight to cure-out the washed off resin. Any spare bottles should be light-blocking.

Comment: @fred_dot_u Curing out the washed off resin works great. Thanks for the idea.